# Spring -mongo full text search

Tags: spring, mongodb, full-text-search

I am developing an app on java. It has mongo db at the back end which stores files(in gridFS). I use spring framework to interact with mongo db.I want to search for text present in the stored documents(pdf,doc,txt files). I know mongo db supports full text search(from 2.4).My question is

1. does spring framework support Full text search? or should we take the help of solr or lucene?
2. If both of the above is possible which is a better option?
3. Wat about indexing?I dont have much knowledge regarding indexing in full text search
4. When will 2.4 be available?

Answer (score 2):

1 Spring does not support full text search within its core features, however, within the spring-data project there are two sub-projects that allow the interaction with solr and elasticsearch, both  of them are full text search engines built in the top of apache lucene, for detailed information look at these links:

https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-solr

2 Depends of your needs, lucene is a low level library, while elasticsearch and solr are out of the box search engines built in the top of lucene, I think that elasticsearch provides better integration with mongodb, through the mongodb-river which support indexing of gridFS attachments. Look at these links:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/

3 You need to clarify this question.

4 I don't know when the mongodb version 2.4 will be available, but don't forget that the full text search is still an experimental feature, and also I think that this feature still does not support gridFS.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB text search will not pull text out of PDF, DOC, or, for that that matter, any files that are stored in GridFS.  From the perspective of MongoDB, GridFS files are uninterpreted binary.

If you'd like to use MongoDB's new text search capabilities to search in different file types, you'll need to do the work in your application to extract text from these files and add the text into documents that you explicitly insert into MongoDB. You can use existing libraries such as [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to do the heavy lifting.  Note that Tika is what Solr/Lucene uses do text extraction from rich-text document types.

As for text search indexing in MongoDB, please refer to the release notes [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#text-indexes)